# Python 3 function printing the same list many times

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need this function to print a list of sentences from the `tastiera.txt` file

```
def frasi_da_file():
    arg1 = input ("percorso file: ")
    arg2 = input("codifica: ")
    if arg1 == "tastiera.txt" and arg2 == "latin1":
        f = open("tastiera.txt")
        raw = f.read()
        for line in raw: 
            q = re.split("\s+", raw)
        print (q)
```

Now its printing the same lists over and over again... I think the problem is in the "for" but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Since `print(q)` is not in the loop, it prints only the most recent value of `q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your code would look like in "good Python":

```
with open("tastiera.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        words = re.split("\s+", line) # words, not q!
        print(words)
```

It is somewhat ok to use regular expressions here, especially if non-white space characters are involved, but `words = line.split()` is more appropriate.

Comment: I would actively discourage regular expressions here ... but yeah +1 (especially now with the addendum on variable names :P)

Comment: @JoranBeasley There may be a reason for custom splitting. But yes, I agree.

Comment: the only good reason i can think of is that the regex provided is not the regex he is actually using...

Comment: Love you guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in raw: 
    print(line.split())
```

should work fine ... you dont need `re.split` ... just use `split`

alternatively

```
for line in raw: 
    q=line.split()  # q is probably not a very appropriate variable name
    print(q)
```